# Ansible - condition if a variable value exists in a variable

Tags: ansible

I am running a task which i only want to execute if the value of a variable that i have previously set does not exist in another variable. I have tried the following but it errors with a templating error:

```
name: get ip address
...
register: ipaddress

name: check cluster
....
register: topology

name: do my task
...
when: not topology is search(ipaddress)
```

Is there any way in ansible to accomplish what i am doing? I'm using version 2.6.

Answer (score 2):

Use [regex_filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html).

> ***Regular Expression Filters***
>
> To search a string with a regex, use the “regex_search” filter:

## search for "foo" in "foobar"

`{{ 'foobar' | regex_search('(foo)') }}`

## will return empty if it cannot find a match

`{{ 'ansible' | regex_search('(foobar)') }}`

## case insensitive search in multiline mode

`{{ 'foo\nBAR' | regex_search("^bar", multiline=True, ignorecase=True) }}`

For your example, making a few assumptions -

```
when: not topology | regex_search(ipaddress, multiline=True)
```

(in a meeting, can't test this, please check it and let me know if it isn't quite right.)

Comment: Didn't work for me. I got the following error: `"The conditional check 'not topology | regex_search(ipaddress, multiline=True)' failed. The error was: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% if not topology | regex_search(ipaddress, multiline=True) %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}): expected string or buffer"`